# Use exteral numpad for shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, xorg, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have a laptop and an **external USB numpad**. I'd like to lay the numpad at my left hand and use it for shortcuts, eg. switching desktops, running apps.

I figured that I've got to make Linux treat that keyboard as **seperate** from the main, by keeping another keymap (eg. when I press 1 on numpad it sends some exotic, nowhere used key).

Long story short : I just want to switch external USB numpad's keymap to keymap that sends weird, nowhere used keys. I know how to map them later.

How can I do it?